# Python: How to synchronize access to a writable array of large numpy arrays (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

I am implementing a specific cache data structure in a machine learning application. The core consists of a list of (large) numpy arrays. The numpy arrays need to be replaced as often and quickly as possible, given the IO limitations. Therefore, there are a few workers that constantly read and prepare data. My current solution is to push a result produced by a worker into a shared queue. A separate process then received the result from the queue and replaces one of the numpy arrays in the list (which is owned by that central process).

I am now wondering whether that is the most elegant solution or whether there are faster solutions. In particular:
1.) As far as I understood the docs, going through a queue is equivalent to a serialization and de-serialization process, which could be slower than using shared memory.
2.) There is some memory overhead if the workers have several objects in the queue (which could have been replaced directly in the list).

I have thought about using a multiprocessing array or the numpy-sharedmem module but both did not really address my scenario. First, my list does not only contain ctypes. Second, each numpy array has a different size and all are independent. Third, I do not need write access to the numpy arrays but only to the 'wrapper' list organizing them.

Also, it should be noted that I am using multiprocessing and not threading as the workers heavily make use of numpy, which should invoke the global interpreter lock essentially all the time.

Questions:
- Is there a way to have a list of numpy arrays in shared memory?
- Is there a 'better' solution compared to the one described above?

Many thanks...

Comment: If possible, please think about the Redis as memory cache. You can put numpy arrays into Redis, and build several clients to check or change the data of the Redis.